# APScheduler to call an async function

Tags: python, apscheduler

I've been having a heck of a time trying to schedule an async function.  My understanding is that the `AsyncIOScheduler` will let me do just that, but in this particular code block, I'm not getting any joy.

Simply running a basic example works no problem:

```
from datetime import datetime 
import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler

async def tick():
    print(f"Tick! The async time is {datetime.now()}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(tick, 'interval', seconds=3)
    scheduler.start()

    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Produces:

```
Tick! The async time is 2021-07-01 18:47:43.503460
Tick! The async time is 2021-07-01 18:47:46.500421
Tick! The async time is 2021-07-01 18:47:49.500208
^C%
```

However my code block is erroring out with various things about callables, and proceeding to tell me that `seed` was never awaited.  It awaits just fine called from `main()` right before setting up the scheduler, but maybe that's a red herring?

I'm no python expert, so please be somewhat gentle :)

Thanks in advance for any clue.

```
import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
import c_seed
import c_logging


client = 'async'
state = 'live'
account = 'spot'

async def main():
    c_logging.logging.info("")
    c,l = await c_seed.init(client,state,account)
    await c_seed.seed(c,l)
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(c_seed.seed(c,l), 'interval', seconds=60)
    scheduler.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c_logging.logging.info("")
    asyncio.run(main())
```

```
2021-07-01 18:43:59,943 [INFO] <module>: c_client
2021-07-01 18:43:59,944 [INFO] <module>: 
2021-07-01 18:43:59,945 [DEBUG] __init__: Using selector: KqueueSelector
2021-07-01 18:43:59,945 [INFO] main: 
2021-07-01 18:43:59,945 [INFO] init: 
2021-07-01 18:43:59,945 [INFO] create: c_client
2021-07-01 18:43:59,945 [INFO] create: c_client -> async
2021-07-01 18:43:59,945 [INFO] create: c_client -> live
2021-07-01 18:44:00,591 [INFO] pairs_list: 
2021-07-01 18:44:00,753 [DEBUG] seed: async seed start
2021-07-01 18:44:07,040 [DEBUG] seed: async seed complete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/Development/main.py", line 58, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main()) 
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/Documents/Development/main.py", line 36, in main
    scheduler.add_job(c_seed.seed(c,l), 'interval', seconds=60)
  File "/Users/Documents/Development/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 439, in add_job
    job = Job(self, **job_kwargs)
  File "/Users/Documents/Development/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._modify(id=id or uuid4().hex, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Documents/Development/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 170, in _modify
    raise TypeError('func must be a callable or a textual reference to one')
TypeError: func must be a callable or a textual reference to one
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'seed' was never awaited
```

Comment: In the working example, the first argument to add_job was a function.  In the non-working example, the first argument was the returned value from a function call.

Comment: Thanks.  My intention is to schedule running the function with arguments.  Is that possible or is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from Paul Cornelius is correct. You have to schedule coroutine functions like any other functions:

```
scheduler.add_job(c_seed.seed, 'interval', seconds=60, args=(c,l))
```

Comment: Thanks for the expansion on Paul's comment.  I'm a little fuzzy on the `add_job` variables.  According to https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/job.html#apscheduler.job.Job there is no reference to `interval` or `seconds`.  Am I missing those references somewhere?

Comment: These arguments are passed directly to the trigger. This is a design that I plan to change in v4.0.